# Lubuntu boots into Terminal. Xorg cant connect to Zlib

Tags: boot, xorg, zlib, libpng

My Lubuntu 18.04 boots strait into the terminal. When I try to start the GUI with `startx` I get the following error message:

```
xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/jonathan/.Xauthority
xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/jonathan/.Xauthority

/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg: /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1: version 'ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/jonathan/.Xauthority
```

I have zlib1.2.11 installed.

I have tried the solution from: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375927 but it did not work for me.

ls -l /usr/local/lib returns

```
in total 35772 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21122658 Aug 31 15:39 libgsl.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18922458 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      949 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.so -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.so.0 -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1098600 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      918 Aug 31 15:39 libgsl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Aug 31 15:39 libgsl.so -> libgsl.so.23.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Aug 31 15:39 libgsl.so.23 -> libgsl.so.23.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12200128 Aug 31 13:39 libgsl.so.23.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   159134 Feb  8 15:29 libz.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       13 Feb  8 18:59 libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       13 Feb  8 18:59 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   121384 Feb  8 15:29 libz.so.1.2.8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Feb  8 15:29 pkgconfig
drwxrwsr-x 4 root staff    4096 Nov 14 08:25 python2.7
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff    4096 Apr 26  2018 python3.6
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff    4096 Aug 17 12:49 R
```

ls -lL /usr/local/lib  returns

```
in total 61996
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21122658 Aug 31 15:39 libgsl.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18922458 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      949 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1098600 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.so -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1098600 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.so.0 -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1098600 Aug 31 15:39 libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      918 Aug 31 15:39 libgsl.la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12200128 Aug 31 15:39 libgsl.so -> libgsl.so.23.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12200128 Aug 31 15:39 libgsl.so.23 -> libgsl.so.23.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12200128 Aug 31 13:39 libgsl.so.23.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   159134 Feb  8 15:29 libz.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   121384 Feb  8 18:59 libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   121384 Feb  8 18:59 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   121384 Feb  8 15:29 libz.so.1.2.8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Feb  8 15:29 pkgconfig
drwxrwsr-x 4 root staff    4096 Nov 14 08:25 python2.7
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff    4096 Apr 26  2018 python3.6
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff    4096 Aug 17 12:49 R
```

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem seems to be with .Xauthority file. Try removing it and reboot: `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority && sudo reboot now`. Please let me know if it works and if so I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but sadly this did not work. I still end up in a terminal screen.

Comment: Can you `ls -l /usr/local/lib`  and `ls -lL /usr/local/lib` and post the results in your question, please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to remove wrongly installed local version of `libz` and reinstall normal one from repository:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1
sudo apt install --reinstall zlib1g
```

Note: do not install system-wide libraries to `/usr/local/lib` next time!

Comment: This also changes nothing. I still get the same error messages.